# How to calculate $\int_a^{\infty} sin(t)/t^n$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

What would be the result of $\int_a^{\infty} sin(t)/t^n$, with $a>0$ and $n$ some constant? How would we be able to derive the formula?

Comment: Is $n$ an integer or just any real constant?

Comment: @naslundx Yes that's an important factor as I too see it.

Comment: you can maybe use: $\int_a^{\infty} \sin(t)/t^n=\Re \int_a^{\infty} \frac{-ie^{it}}{t^n}$

Answer (score 4):

Just apply integration by parts multiple times till you are left with
$$\int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt\quad\text{or}\quad\int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos t}{t}\,dt,\tag{1}$$
then notice that:
$$ \int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin t}{t}\,dt = \int_{a}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-xt}\sin t\,dx\,dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos a+x\sin a}{1+x^2}e^{-ax}\,dx$$
as well as:
$$ \int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos t}{t}\,dt = \int_{a}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-xt}\cos t\,dx\,dt = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x\cos a-\sin a}{1+x^2}e^{-ax}\,dx.$$